# MySql how to get data between 2 date, if empty return 0

Tags: mysql

I have a query as below

```
SELECT * FROM salesData 
WHERE date BETWEEN "2020-10-01" AND "2020-10-05" 
ORDER BY date
```

will get result of

```
-------------------------
| sales   | date        |
-------------------------
| 150.00  | 2020-10-01  |
| 200.00  | 2020-10-04  |
| 250.00  | 2020-10-05  |
-------------------------
```

and I wish to get a result from every date in the range even it is empty data as below

```
-------------------------
| sales   | date        |
-------------------------
| 150.00  | 2020-10-01  |
| 0.00    | 2020-10-02  |
| 0.00    | 2020-10-03  |
| 200.00  | 2020-10-04  |
| 250.00  | 2020-10-05  |
-------------------------
```

is there any function in MySql able to do it?

Comment: Generate dates list in specified range (use CTE) then LEFTJOIN your data to it.

Comment: For this we tend to generate a sequence of every date and then LEFT JOIN the data onto it. What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: im using 10.4.13-MariaDB, i think Akina answer is work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT '2020-10-01' AS `date`
       UNION ALL
         SELECT `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY
         FROM cte
         WHERE `date` < '2020-10-05' )
SELECT `date`, COALESCE(salesData.sales, 0) sales
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN salesData USING (`date`)
```

MySQL 8+ needed.